# IncompatibleClassChangeError Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, stripe-payments

After updating Build Tools and SDK my application crashes in my Payment Fragment as soon as I want to add a new Card.

I have had this problem before with Stripe because I was using 'com.stripe:stripe-android:+'
Then I switched to stable version 1.0.1 which worked fine.

Once I updated to BuildTools 25.0.1 and Stripe 2.0.2 it crashes with IncompatibleClassChange Error, and if it happenes to switch back to buildtools 23 and Stripe 1.0.1 i get the same issue.

Please check Screenshot from LogCat
[image]

CardEditFragment.java

```
package com.cooltechworks.creditcarddesign;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.text.InputFilter;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.cooltechworks.creditcarddesign.pager.AddCardTkn;
import com.cooltechworks.creditcarddesign.pager.CardCVVFragment;
import com.cooltechworks.creditcarddesign.pager.CardFragmentAdapter;
import com.cooltechworks.creditcarddesign.pager.CardFragmentAdapter.ICardEntryCompleteListener;

import com.stripe.android.Stripe;
import com.stripe.android.TokenCallback;
import com.stripe.android.model.Card;
import com.stripe.android.model.Token;

import static com.cooltechworks.creditcarddesign.CreditCardUtils.EXTRA_CARD_CVV;
import static com.cooltechworks.creditcarddesign.CreditCardUtils.EXTRA_CARD_EXPIRY;
import static com.cooltechworks.creditcarddesign.CreditCardUtils.EXTRA_CARD_HOLDER_NAME;
import static com.cooltechworks.creditcarddesign.CreditCardUtils.*;


public class CardEditFragment extends Fragment {


    //public static final String STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = "pk_live_xxxxxxxxxxx";
    public static String STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY = "pk_test_xxxxxxxxxxx";

    private TextView tvNext;
    private TextView tvPrevious;


    int mLastPageSelected = 0;
    private CreditCardView mCreditCardView;

    private ViewPager pager;

    private String mCardNumber;
    private String mCVV;
    private String mCardHolderName;
    private String mExpiry;

    private String mPostcode;

    private CardFragmentAdapter mCardAdapter;

    private AddCardTkn tknHandlerDelegate;
    private View editCardView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final View editCardView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_card_edit, container, false);

        this.editCardView = editCardView;


        tknHandlerDelegate = getActivity().getIntent().getParcelableExtra("interface");

        tvNext = (TextView) editCardView.findViewById(R.id.next);
        tvPrevious = (TextView) editCardView.findViewById(R.id.previous);

        tvNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                pager = (ViewPager) editCardView.findViewById(R.id.card_field_container_pager);

                int max = pager.getAdapter().getCount();

                if (pager.getCurrentItem() == max - 1) {
                    // if last card.
                    onDoneTapped();
                } else {
                    showNext();
                }
            }
        });
        tvPrevious.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPrevious();
            }
        });

        setKeyboardVisibility(true);
        mCreditCardView = (CreditCardView) editCardView.findViewById(R.id.credit_card_view);


        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            checkParams(savedInstanceState);
        } else {
            checkParams(getActivity().getIntent().getExtras());
        }

        loadPager();

        return editCardView;

    }

    private void checkParams(Bundle bundle) {


        if (bundle == null) {
            return;
        }
        mCardHolderName = bundle.getString(EXTRA_CARD_HOLDER_NAME);
        mCVV = bundle.getString(EXTRA_CARD_CVV);
        mExpiry = bundle.getString(EXTRA_CARD_EXPIRY);
        mCardNumber = bundle.getString(EXTRA_CARD_NUMBER);


        mCreditCardView.setCVV(mCVV);
        mCreditCardView.setCardHolderName(mCardHolderName);
        mCreditCardView.setCardExpiry(mExpiry);
        mCreditCardView.setCardNumber(mCardNumber);


        if (mCardAdapter != null) {
            mCardAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

    public void refreshNextButton() {

        ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) editCardView.findViewById(R.id.card_field_container_pager);

        int max = pager.getAdapter().getCount();

        int text = R.string.next;

        if (pager.getCurrentItem() == max - 1) {
            text = R.string.done;
        }

        ((TextView) editCardView.findViewById(R.id.next)).setText(text);
    }

    public void loadPager() {

        ViewPager pager;
        pager = (ViewPager) editCardView.findViewById(R.id.card_field_container_pager);
        if (pager != null) {
            pager.addOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
                }

                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    CardCVVFragment cvvFrag = (CardCVVFragment) mCardAdapter.getItem(2);
                    int maxLength = 3;

                    if (mCardNumber.length() == 15) {
                        cvvFrag.isAmex = true;
                        maxLength = 4;
                    } else {

                        cvvFrag.isAmex = false;
                    }

                    InputFilter[] fArray = new InputFilter[1];
                    fArray[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(maxLength);
                    cvvFrag.getCardCVVView().setFilters(fArray);
                    mCardAdapter.focus(position);

                    if (position == 2 && !cvvFrag.isAmex) {
                        mCreditCardView.showBack();
                    } else if ((position == 1 && mLastPageSelected == 2) || (position == 3 && !cvvFrag.isAmex)) {
                        mCreditCardView.showFront();
                    }

                    mLastPageSelected = position;

                    refreshNextButton();

                }

                @Override
                public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
                }
            });
            pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(5);
        }
        mCardAdapter = new CardFragmentAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), getActivity().getIntent().getExtras());
        mCardAdapter.setOnCardEntryCompleteListener(new ICardEntryCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCardEntryComplete(int currentIndex) {

                showNext();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCardEntryEdit(int currentIndex, String entryValue) {
                switch (currentIndex) {
                    case 0:
                        mCardNumber = entryValue.replace(CreditCardUtils.SPACE_SEPERATOR, "");
                        mCreditCardView.setCardNumber(mCardNumber);
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mExpiry = entryValue;
                        mCreditCardView.setCardExpiry(entryValue);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mCVV = entryValue;
                        mCreditCardView.setCVV(entryValue);
                        break;
                    case 3:
                        mCardHolderName = entryValue;
                        mCreditCardView.setCardHolderName(entryValue);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        mPostcode = entryValue;
                        mCreditCardView.setCardPostcode(entryValue);
                        break;
                }
            }
        });

        pager.setAdapter(mCardAdapter);
    }

    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

        outState.putString(EXTRA_CARD_CVV, mCVV);
        outState.putString(EXTRA_CARD_HOLDER_NAME, mCardHolderName);
        outState.putString(EXTRA_CARD_EXPIRY, mExpiry);
        outState.putString(EXTRA_CARD_NUMBER, mCardNumber);
        outState.putString(EXTRA_REGISTERED_POSTCODE, mPostcode);


        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    }


    public void showPrevious() {

        final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) editCardView.findViewById(R.id.card_field_container_pager);
        int currentIndex = pager.getCurrentItem();

        if (currentIndex - 1 >= 0) {
            pager.setCurrentItem(currentIndex - 1);
        }

        refreshNextButton();
    }

    public void showNext() {

        final ViewPager pager = (ViewPager) editCardView.findViewById(R.id.card_field_container_pager);
        CardFragmentAdapter adapter = (CardFragmentAdapter) pager.getAdapter();

        int max = adapter.getCount();
        int currentIndex = pager.getCurrentItem();

        if (currentIndex + 1 < max) {

            pager.setCurrentItem(currentIndex + 1);
        } else {
            // completed the card entry.
            setKeyboardVisibility(false);
        }

        refreshNextButton();
    }

    private void onDoneTapped() {
        if (mCardHolderName == null || mCardHolderName.equals(""))
        {
            handleError("Please enter the cardholders name");
            return;
        }
        if (mPostcode == null || mPostcode.equals(""))
        {
            handleError("Please enter the cardholders postcode");
            return;
        }
        if (mExpiry == null || mExpiry.length() != 5) {
            handleError("The expiration date that you entered is invalid");
            return;
        }
        String month = mExpiry.substring(0, 2);
        String year = mExpiry.substring(3);

        Card card = new Card(mCardNumber,
                Integer.parseInt(month),
                Integer.parseInt(year),
                mCVV,
                mCardHolderName,
                "",
                "",
                "",
                "",
                mPostcode,
                "",
                "");
        boolean validation = card.validateCard();

        if (validation) {
            startProgress();
            new Stripe().createToken(
                    card,
                    STRIPE_PUBLISHABLE_KEY,
                    new TokenCallback() {
                        public void onSuccess(Token token) {
                            //Send to server
                            Log.d("Stripe Token", token.toString());

                            //For purpose of booking while Not registered yet
                            Bundle appointmentInfo = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
                            tknHandlerDelegate.addCard(token.getId(), getActivity(), appointmentInfo);

                        }

                        public void onError(Exception error) {
                            handleError(error.getLocalizedMessage());
                            finishProgress();
                        }
                    });
        } else if (!card.validateNumber()) {
            handleError("The card number that you entered is invalid");
        } else if (!card.validateExpiryDate()) {
            handleError("The expiration date that you entered is invalid");
        } else if (!card.validateCVC()) {
            handleError("The CVC code that you entered is invalid");
        } else {
            handleError("The card details that you entered are invalid");
        }


    }

    private void startProgress() {
        tknHandlerDelegate.showProgress(getActivity());

    }

    private void finishProgress() {
        tknHandlerDelegate.hideProgress(getActivity());
    }

    private void handleError(String error) {

        tknHandlerDelegate.handleError(error, getActivity());
    }

    // from the link above
    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);


        // Checks whether a hardware keyboard is available
        if (newConfig.hardKeyboardHidden == Configuration.HARDKEYBOARDHIDDEN_NO) {

            LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout) editCardView.findViewById(R.id.parent);
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) parent.getLayoutParams();
            layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, 0);
            parent.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        }
    }

    private void setKeyboardVisibility(boolean visible) {

        final EditText editText = (EditText) editCardView.findViewById(R.id.card_number_field);


        if (!visible) {

            InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
            imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(editText.getWindowToken(), 0);
        } else {
            getActivity().getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
        }
    }

}
```

I have also included my build.gradle(Module : app)

```
    buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"

    sourceSets.main {
        jni.srcDirs = []
        jniLibs.srcDir 'src/main/libs'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.pushdr.application"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 17

        ndk {
            moduleName "ndkVidyoSample"
        }
    }

    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://github.com/FireZenk/maven-repo/raw/master/' }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenCentral()
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }


    productFlavors {
        armv7a
                {
                    ndk
                            {
                                abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"

                            }
                }
        fat ///This build contain multi architecture binary
    }
}

dependencies {

    //facebook SDK

    //Used for Signal R + Chat
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk-android.jar')
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')
    compile files('libs/signalr-client-sdk.jar')

    //Used for PIN entry
    compile project(':pinentry')

    //Menu Drawer
    compile project(':materialTabs')

    //Credit Card Payment Libraries
    compile project(':creditcarddesign')

    //Audio waves
    compile project(':audiowaves')


    compile('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.6.4@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }

    compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[4,5)'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.2.0'
    compile 'com.roger.gifloadinglibrary:gifloadinglibrary:1.0.0'
    compile 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.5.0'
    compile 'com.synnapps:carouselview:0.0.9'
    compile 'com.ragnarok.rxcamera:lib:0.0.4'
    compile 'pl.droidsonroids.gif:android-gif-drawable:1.1.17'
    compile 'com.stripe:stripe-android:2.0.2'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.4.1'
    compile 'com.github.2359media:EasyAndroidAnimations:0.8'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:crossfader:1.3.7@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:crossfadedrawerlayout:0.3.4@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:itemanimators:0.2.4@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:google-material-typeface:2.2.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:fontawesome-typeface:4.4.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.mikepenz:octicons-typeface:3.0.0.1@aar'
    compile 'com.github.amlcurran.showcaseview:library:5.4.3'
    compile 'com.jzxiang.pickerview:TimePickerDialog:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.4'
}
```

I also checked a couple more posts on StackOverflow about incompatibleClassChangeErrors but did not help me resolving this issue.

Previous versions of APKs of this App work fine so I am quite consfused of why this would be caused! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Would you mind opening an issue about this on the repository? https://github.com/stripe/stripe-android/issues

Comment: @Ywain Thank you for coming back to me, I will open an issue now.

Comment: @Ywain issue has been opened.

Comment: @Ywain, please close thread in Github as I have found a solution. This message was comming from one of my libraries using outdated buildtools and stripe versions. I have updated the code and everything runs as it supposed to! Thank you for your time!